# Getting Null Result from web Service in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to use a web service in my asp.net project. I add the web reference and trying to use the some of the functions of that service.I am trying to fetch some values from the web service.For this process First I am sending some data to web service for process.This is the code which I am trying to use

```
 wsezp.ApiService ws = new wsezp.ApiService();
        ws.Recharge("589746656", "608669", "1234567890", "5", "10", "12345");
        wsezp.Result rs = new wsezp.Result();
        string Requestid = rs.reqid;
        string Status = rs.status;
        Response.Write("Status of Requestid " + Requestid + "is " + Status);
```

As per my Document I will get my result like this

```
<recharge>
<reqid>0000<reqid/>
<status>SUCCESS</status>
<remark>recharge_transaction_id</remark>
<balance>your api balance</balance>
<mn>mobile number</mn>
<field1>operator transaction id</field1>
</recharge>
```

But I am getting null in the strings which I declare. Please tell me how can I use the web  service for post the request and get back the result from the web service

Comment: See what is the exact result using a tool like fiddler.

Comment: It does not get anything on fiddler I check it too @sdeep

Comment: Is your web service getting hit ? If yes, what parameters is it getting exactly ? What is getting in and is there any exception ?

Comment: when I hit my recharge function i get the result ws.Result @sdeep

Comment: wsezp.Result rs = ws.Recharge(...

Comment: thanks genius :) Its work.. Please post answer so that I can mark @Kirby

Comment: I edited my answer post for you to mark. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me as if you are creating a new result. Are sure the call to recharge doesn't return the result you are looking for ? That would make sense.

wsezp.Result rs = ws.Recharge(...